# Programmatically invoke pan tool

Tags: matlab, plot, pan

In [matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab), how to change plot pan programmatically?

the function syntax from the documentation:

```
pan on
pan xon
pan yon
pan off
pan
pan(figure_handle,...)
h = pan(figure_handle)
```

the code seems to be used for enabling and disabling the tool and decide the pan direction *vertically* or *horizontally* , How could I change plot with handle `pHandle` using `pan` function or whatever programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the pan, I generally use the axis limit functions

```
xlim(aHandle, [xlow xhigh])
ylim(aHandle, [ylow yhigh])
axis(aHandle, [xliw xhigh ylow yhigh])
```

To specifically pan only, for example 5 units to the left, you could use:

```
xlim(aHandle, xlim(pHandle)+5);
```

This last function use the `xlim` command to read the current x axis limits, adds 5, and then uses the same function to set the x limits to a value that is 5 higher.

If the axis handle `aHandle` is ommitted, then the result of `gca` is used.

Comment: Too fast answer to be accepted :D, Great answer, but please write code explicitly using `pHandle` as plot handle for example for horizontal pan with `10`.

Comment: You're right.  Explicitly specifying the axis handle is good practice.  Updated.

Comment: you can get the axes handle from `aHandle = get(pHandle,'Parent');`