# Refresh axis with datetime variables for proper tick distance

Tags: matlab, datetime

I open a .fig-file from a colleague, and then want to add some of my own data to it. Unfortunately, the original figure is too large on my screen, so I use

```
set(f2, 'Position', [100, 100, 800, 600]);
```

to keep it small.
This squeezes the x-axis, but for some reason the number of ticks is not reduced, leading to far too dense tick marks. As soon as I select the "Pan" tool and slightly move the graph, the tick marks update to regular, automatic distance.

What code can I use to do this automatically? I'm aware I can manually adjust the tick marks, but this will have to work for multiple datasets of different lengths & intervals.

Other relevant code: (Date is of the DateTime format)

```
f2=open('originaldata.fig')
h2=plot(date,newdata,'LineWidth',3);
xlim(datenum([date(1)-minutes(8) date(end)+minutes(8)]))
set(f2, 'Position', [100, 100, 800, 600])
```

Comment: Have you tried panning programmatically to see if the figure automatically corrects? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14663412/programatically-invokve-pan-tool you can get the limits out of the figure

Comment: Heh... I have no idea why this didn't occur to me - I use the xlim function all the time! Just defining my xlim *after* the repositioning line solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is embarrassingly simple.
One "trick" that worked was to add the title until after resizing the figure. Adding the title makes the graph a bit smaller and thus re-draws is.

However, the easiest way is just to define the xlim after the resizing. So, instead of:

```
f2=open('originaldata.fig')
h2=plot(date,newdata,'LineWidth',3);
xlim(datenum([date(1)-minutes(8) date(end)+minutes(8)]))
set(f2, 'Position', [100, 100, 800, 600])
```

You do:

```
f2=open('originaldata.fig')
h2=plot(date,newdata,'LineWidth',3);
set(f2, 'Position', [100, 100, 800, 600])
xlim(datenum([date(1)-minutes(8) date(end)+minutes(8)]))
```

That way, you basically "pan" (which is nothing more than changing the span of the axes) and the problem is solved.

Dan (in the comments), thanks for the nudge!